# Size mismatch error when attempting to load_pretrained() after save_pretrained() of the same transformer model

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

I've created a model, trained it, and saved it as follows:

```
# Create output directory if needed
if not os.path.exists(args.output_dir) and args.local_rank in [-1, 0]:
    os.makedirs(args.output_dir)

logger.info("Saving model checkpoint to %s", args.output_dir)
# Save a trained model, configuration and tokenizer using `save_pretrained()`.
# They can then be reloaded using `from_pretrained()`
model_to_save = (
    model.module if hasattr(model, "module") else model
)  # Take care of distributed/parallel training
model_to_save.save_pretrained(args.output_dir)
tokenizer.save_pretrained(args.output_dir)

# Good practice: save your training arguments together with the trained model
torch.save(args, os.path.join(args.output_dir, "training_args.bin"))
```

I later try to load the same model as follows:

```
dir_to_trained_model = args.output_dir

config_trained = BertConfig.from_pretrained(dir_to_trained_model)
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained(dir_to_trained_model)

model_trained = BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(dir_to_trained_model, config = config_trained)
```

However, I experience the following error at the final `model_trained = ...` line:

```
============================================================
<class 'transformers.tokenization_bert.BertTokenizer'>
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-5519b2c94546> in <module>
      6 tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained(dir_to_trained_model)
      7 
----> 8 model_trained = BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(dir_to_trained_model, config = config_trained)

/home/s1097572/DNABERT/src/transformers/modeling_utils.py in from_pretrained(cls, pretrained_model_name_or_path, *model_args, **kwargs)
    737                 raise RuntimeError(
    738                     "Error(s) in loading state_dict for {}:\n\t{}".format(
--> 739                         model.__class__.__name__, "\n\t".join(error_msgs)
    740                     )
    741                 )

RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for BertForSequenceClassification:
    size mismatch for bert.embeddings.word_embeddings.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([4101, 768]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([30522, 768]).
```

It seems the model and the config are incompatible, which doesn't make sense given that both source files originated from the same model. I am using Transformers=2.5.0 if that makes a difference. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you modify the model or the tokenizer in any way before training? such as adding a new word, adding a new layer or so

Comment: The model was modified before training, yes. What files are mismatched? Everything loaded at the second code chunk is being saved to file after changing the model and training it before the first code chunk. What underlying parameters are still present in the precursor model when saving the reparametrized, trained model?

Comment: So I found the discrepancy. vocab.txt has 4101 files but config.json has the parameter '"vocab_size": 30522'. Any idea why that 'vocab_size' is being written with the wrong shape?